How to Compute Riemannian Gradient (on the Sphere)
I'm trying to explicitly compute the Riemannian Gradient of a function $h : \mathbb{S}^{N-1} \to \mathbb{R},$ and, by extension, the "Jacobian matrix" of some function $f:\mathbb{S}^{N-1} \to \mathbb{R}^{N-1}.$ I'm a little new to the subject, so any advice is appreciated!
Fix the canonical Riemannian metric $g_p: T_p \mathbb{S}^{N-1} \times T_p \mathbb{S}^{N-1} \to \mathbb{R},$ which is $$g_p \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} b_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}a_i b_i.$$ Then consider some function $h : \mathbb{S}^{N-1} \to \mathbb{R}.$ The definition of the Riemannian gradient of $h$ is the unique vector field $\nabla h$ on $M$ so that $g_p(\nabla h_p, X_p) = X_p h$ for all vector fields $X$. Also, if an orthonormal frame field $E$ is given, I would like to compute the gradient in that basis. I don't think I really understand how to actually compute this in practice. I'm under the impression is that one can compute this simply by computing the normal gradient of $h$ and then project it onto $T_p(\mathbb{S}^{N-1})$ by multiplying by the projection operator $I - p p^T,$ but I'm not sure of how to relate the two (i.e., I'm not sure how to show that this satisfies the definition of Riemannian gradient).
Regarding the Jacobian matrix, I would like to do the following, which follows page 302 of Adler-Taylor, Random Fields and Geometry. Let $(M, g)$ be an $(N-1)$-dimensional Riemannian Manifold (as is the case above), and let $f : M \to \mathbb{R}^{N-1}$ be $C^1$. Fix an orthonormal frame field $E$. For a scalar function $h$, they define $$(\nabla h_E)_i = \nabla h_{E_i} \stackrel{\Delta}{=} (\nabla h)(E_i) = E_i h,$$ where $\nabla$ is the Riemannian gradient defined above. Then the Jacobian matrix $\nabla f_E$, for $f = (f^1, f^2, \dots, f^{N-1}),$ denotes the $(N-1) \times (N-1)$ matrix with elements $\nabla f_{E_i}^j.$ For this last part, I'm (a) not sure how to write down the orthonormal frame field for $\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$ and (b) I guess I would need to compute the Riemannian gradient in that basis.
I feel like this must be a moderately standard thing, so any directions would be super helpful!

Not an answer, just noting that in the expression for the canonical Riemannian metric $g$ it appears $\partial/\partial x_i$ is an orthonormal frame. On the other hand, the notation suggests a coordinate frame. But there exists no local orthonormal coordinate frame on a sphere, because a sphere of dimension at least $2$ is not flat. <> If you're free to pick coordinates, I recommend stereographic coordinates: the metric components constitute a scalar matrix, which is easy to invert.
